# Vue 3 + Typescript - How to watch a class property

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, watch

I have recently started a project using CLI of Vue3 with Typescript and noticed that the `vue-class-component` is rather different. In fact, I am not sure if this project is really compatible with the latest Vue 3 functionality.

I came across these two threads: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/406 and https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/406#issuecomment-745490016 so I am not sure if `vue-class-component` is the way to go these days.

Currently, I am trying to figure out how to Watch a property pass to a component but none of the stuff such as `@Watch` or `@Prop` are available anymore.

Can somebody provide an example on how to go about this?

Here is a snippet and I would like to know how to watch the `msg` property value:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";

@Options({
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
})
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  msg!: string;

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

For Vue 2 you would use [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator)

For Vue 3 - for now - you can use [vue-facing-decorator](https://github.com/facing-dev/vue-facing-decorator) which has a complete implementation of decorators.

Both repositories have similar usage:

```js
// import { Prop, Watch, Component, Vue } from " vue-property-decorator"; // Vue2
import { Prop, Watch, Component, Vue } from "vue-facing-decorator"; // Vue3

@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  @Prop
    msg: string
  
  @Watch('msg')
  methodName (newMsg: string, oldMsg: string) {
    console.log(`msg just changed from ${oldMsg} to ${newMsg}`);
  }
}
```

> **Edit**: `vue-property-decorator` recently started supporting Vue 3, as for today there is a release candidate : `npm install vue-property-decorator@10.0.0-rc.3`, further releases might be more
> stable.

Answer (score 0):

We use the `vue-property-decorator` package, and it works quite nicely.

https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator#-watchpath-string-options-watchoptions---decorator

Edit: I just saw that you are using Vue 3 and I am note quite sure, if it is supported. I will still not delete this answer, because it might help you or someone else.

Cheers

Comment: I am looking for a Vue3 solution. I have read several threads and I couldn't find a solution that is still useful.

Comment: Yeah, I edited my answer. Did you consider using the beta version of this package, which has Vue 3 Support? https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/tree/next (See issue https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator/issues/294)

Comment: @CunningFatalist They are deprecated, use `vue-facing-decorator` instead.